# How to make navbar sticky using Tailwind CSS uitillity classes?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, tailwind-css

I am using 'sticky' className from Tailwind CSS Utility classes but it is not doing anything.

```
<div className='sticky w-[100%] z-50'>
              {show && <Banner handleBannerClose={handleBannerClose} />}
              <Navbar handleChange={handleThemeChange} toggleCart={toggleCart} handleMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter} handleMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave} toggleAvatar={toggleAvatar} />
</div>
```

If I use 'fixed' class instead of 'sticky', it works as a sticky navbar but it covers the body section.

[image]

And if I give margin-top to the section to drag it down, navbar still fixed on top of that section.

[image]

I tried to give margin-top to the section in body so it drags down, but it drags down and so is navbar.
What is the proper way to overcome this problem with tailwind Css?

Comment: You should probably set the position if you use sticky: `sticky top-0 z-10`.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to set the position of the `sticky` div.

In your case set it to `top-0`.

---

Updated Code:

```
<div className='sticky top-0 w-[100%] z-50'>  
              {show && <Banner handleBannerClose={handleBannerClose} />}
              <Navbar handleChange={handleThemeChange} toggleCart={toggleCart} handleMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter} handleMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave} toggleAvatar={toggleAvatar} />
</div>
```